# kubernetes nodes keep rebooting when using rook volumes

Tags: kubernetes, linux-kernel, ceph, cephfs, rook-storage

Several days ago I faced a problem when my nodes were rebooting constantly

My stack:

- 1 master, 2 workers k8s-cluster built with kubeadm (v1.17.1-00)
- Ubuntu 18.04 x86_64 4.15.0-74-generic
- Flannel cni plugin (v0.11.0)
- Rook (v1.2) cephfs for storage. Ceph was deployed in the same cluster, where my application lives

I was able to run ceph cluster, but when I tried to deploy my application, that was using my rook-volumes, suddenly my pods were starting to die

I got this message when I used `kubectl describe pods/name` command:

`Pod sandbox changed, it will be killed and re-created`

In the k8s events I got:

`<Node name> has been rebooted`

After some time node comes to life but eventually dies in 2-3 minutes.

I tried to drain my node and connect back to my cluster but after that some another node was getting this error.

I looked into the system error logs of a failed node by command `journalctl -p 3`.

And found, that logs were flooded with these messages: `kernel: cache_from_obj: Wrong slab cache. inode_cache but object is from ceph_inode_info`.

After googling this problem, I found this issue:
https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/2616

It turned out, that cephfs just doesn't work with some versions of Linux kernel!! 
For me neither of these worked:

- Ubuntu 19.04 x86_64 5.0.0-32-generic
- Ubuntu 18.04 x86_64 4.15.0-74-generic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution

Cephfs doesn't work with some versions of Linux kernel. Upgrade your kernel. I finally got it working on Ubuntu 18.04 x86_64 5.0.0-38-generic

Github issue, that helped me:
https://github.com/coreos/bugs/issues/2616

This is indeed a tricky issue, I was struggling to find a solution, and I spent A LOT of time trying to understand what was happening. I hope this information will help some one, cause there is not so much information on google.